# Too many columns in GROUP BY

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I'm trying to aggregate some data, but I've a problem. There's my query (using 3 tables):

```
SELECT
            ufc.counter_id,
            gcrvf.goal_id,
            gcrvf.date_of_visit,
            ufc.utm_campaign,
            ufc.utm_source,
            ufc.utm_medium,
            ufc.utm_content,
            ufc.utm_term,
            ufc.original_join_id,
            max(gcrvf.last_update_time) AS last_update_time,
            sum(gcrvf.conversions) AS conversions, 
            c.name AS counter_name,
            c.owner_login AS owner_login,
            c.status AS counter_status,
            concat(g.goal_source,CAST('Goal','text')) AS metric_type,
            multiIf(g.is_retargeting = 0,'non-retargeting',g.is_retargeting = 1,'retargeting',NULL) AS metric_key,
            concat(g.name,' (',CAST(gcrvf.goal_id,'String'),')') AS metric_name
        FROM connectors_yandex_metrika.goal_conversions_report_v_final AS gcrvf
        INNER JOIN connectors_yandex_metrika.utm_for_collect AS ufc ON gcrvf.counter_id = ufc.counter_id
        LEFT JOIN connectors_yandex_metrika.counter AS c ON gcrvf.counter_id = c.id
        LEFT JOIN connectors_yandex_metrika.goal AS g ON gcrvf.goal_id = g.id
        WHERE 
            ((gcrvf.utm_campaign = ufc.utm_campaign) OR (ufc.utm_campaign IS NULL)) 
            AND ((gcrvf.utm_source = ufc.utm_source) OR (ufc.utm_source IS NULL)) 
            AND ((gcrvf.utm_medium = ufc.utm_medium) OR (ufc.utm_medium IS NULL)) 
            AND ((gcrvf.utm_content = ufc.utm_content) OR (ufc.utm_content IS NULL))
            AND ((gcrvf.utm_term = ufc.utm_term ) OR (ufc.utm_term IS NULL))
        GROUP BY
            ufc.counter_id,
            gcrvf.date_of_visit,
            gcrvf.goal_id,
            ufc.utm_campaign,
            ufc.utm_source,
            ufc.utm_medium,
            ufc.utm_content,
            ufc.utm_term,
            ufc.original_join_id,
            c.name,
            c.owner_login,
            c.status,
            metric_type,
            metric_key,
            metric_name
```

I have to `GROUP BY` by almost all columns. Is it a real problem?

Columns  `ufc.original_join_id`, `c.name,c.owner_login`, `c.status`, `metric_type`, `metric_key,metric_name` are not necessary here. I added them to group by just because I need these columns. And I want to ask: any way to make it more abbreviated? Any ways to avoid unnecessary columns from group by? Or it's okay?

And my second question: does ClickHouse cache `right table` when we use JOINs? So I always should put huge table as left table?

Comment: "I have to GROUP BY by almost all columns" - that's what SQL requires you to do to make those aggregated functions work. "Is it a real problem?" - you tell us. Does it work acceptably fast? If so, it's not a problem.

Comment: An alternative would be to aggregate in a correlated subquery, but there's nothing wrong with the query.

Comment: Why do you put _some_ JOIN conditions in the WHERE clause?

Comment: And, depending on type of relationships, you might need to aggregate in a subquery before joining. (To avoid same value counted several times.)

Comment: you should only group columns that make up your unique grouping tuple. If for any unique such tuple, `c.owner_login` is the same you can just use `any(c.owner_login)` to get such value

Comment: @SergioTulentsev this table contains 120 million records and this query takes about 40s to be completed. It's kinda okay time for us 
@jarlh when I'm using conditions from `WHERE` inside JOIN ON, it throws an error `Unsupported JOIN ON conditions` This ```inner join connectors_yandex_metrika.utm_sessions_report r on u.counter_id = r.counter_id 
  and (
    u.utm_campaign = r.utm_campaign 
    or u.utm_campaign IS NULL
  ) ``` will not work

Answer (score 0):

All columns are required in the group by. It is not possible to leaf some columns out which where mentioned as select columns.

Depending on your indexed columns you can improve the speed of the query. You should try to make an index on the key columns.

The Database will handle the cache logic for you. Depending on how often you execute the query.